# rspec - how to use let! to setup 2 variables?

Tags: ruby, rspec, let

I currently have:

```
describe 'least number of moves from x to y' do

  it 'has a populated chessboard' do
    @wp='white-pawn'
    @bp='black-pawn'

    expect(ChessBoard.new.populate_new_board).to eq [
      ['white-castle','white-knight','white-bishop','white-queen','white-king','white-bishop','white-knight','white-castle'],
      [@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp],
      ['black-castle','black-knight','black-bishop','black-king','black-queen','black-bishop','black-knight','black-castle']]
  end
```

which works ok.
I want to change to use let!, so I tried:

```
describe 'least number of moves from x to y' do

  let!(:wp){'white-pawn'}
  let!(:bp){'black-pawn'}

  it 'has a populated chessboard' do
    expect(ChessBoard.new.populate_new_board).to eq [
      ['white-castle','white-knight','white-bishop','white-queen','white-king','white-bishop','white-knight','white-castle'],
      [@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp,@wp],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp,@bp],
      ['black-castle','black-knight','black-bishop','black-king','black-queen','black-bishop','black-knight','black-castle']]
  end
```

but it fails because I now get nil for all the @bp and @wp values.

How to fix, i.e. write the let syntax correct for the expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `wp` instead of `@wp` and `bp` instead of `@bp`, because those are methods, not instance variables:

```
describe 'least number of moves from x to y' do

  let!(:wp){'white-pawn'}
  let!(:bp){'black-pawn'}

  it 'has a populated chessboard' do

    expect(ChessBoard.new.populate_new_board).to eq [
      ['white-castle','white-knight','white-bishop','white-queen','white-king','white-bishop','white-knight','white-castle'],
      [wp,wp,wp,wp,wp,wp,wp,wp],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [bp,bp,bp,bp,bp,bp,bp,bp],
      ['black-castle','black-knight','black-bishop','black-king','black-queen','black-bishop','black-knight','black-castle']]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`let!` was setting up local methods, not instance variables so this worked:

```
 it 'has a populated chessboard' do
    expect(ChessBoard.new.populate_new_board).to eq [
      ['white-castle','white-knight','white-bishop','white-queen','white-king','white-bishop','white-knight','white-castle'],
      [wp,wp,wp,wp,wp,wp,wp,wp],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
      [bp,bp,bp,bp,bp,bp,bp,bp],
      ['black-castle','black-knight','black-bishop','black-king','black-queen','black-bishop','black-knight','black-castle']]
  end
```